# Magento 2 backend form date time form field

Tags: magento2, forms, datetime

How can I get datetime as form field.I have used below code able to select date but there is no time. How can I get time also as input field.

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'time',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'time',
                'label' => __('Time'),
                'title' => __('Time'), 
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
                'singleClick'=> true,
                'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
                'time'=>true
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'time',
            'date',
            [
                'name' => 'time',
                'label' => __('Time'),
                'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'time_format' => 'hh:mm:ss'
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Ho Do I add the backend form